# passing a modelview object to the business layer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am having a modelview object in my view and I want to pass it to a function in my business layer at compile time, I got error:

```
public static bool CreerNouveauHistoEntity(object model)
{
    bool success = false;
    object var = model.Commentaire; 

}
```

There is no definition for Commentaire.

If I remove the line object var = model.Commentaire; , it compile fine

What can I do about it ?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` doesn't have Commentaire as a property.

You should either cast it :

```
var obj = ((YourClass)model).Commentaire;
```

or define a proper argument:

```
public static bool CreerNouveauHistoEntity(YourClass model)
```

Comment: My viewModel is having the commentaire definition, and my target entity model is having the hm_commentaire, how would I do the mapping in such ?

Comment: In my opinion you should do one of three : 1. Make a function on your business model that will expect an argument a view model and will create a business object out of the view. 2. Cast it as i said. 3. If you only need this property, then pass only this property as an argument.

Comment: Thanks Giannis, I think I will be using the solution 3, as I cannot pass my model view as such to my business layer